# How to support multiple screen sizes on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an apps for both phone and tablet, but the problem is that when we run it on a tablet then the image that we have used in the app doesn't stretch and looks different. But we want to develop it like on the phone. Is it possible or not if yes then how? I have used image .jpg and .png.I think the problem is the image, the java code is perfect.

Comment: To be more specific, what exactly do you mean by "its look becomes different".. ? You mean to say that the image size remains small only..?

Comment: yes swayam, yeah image size becomes small

Comment: Then use images of different resolution in different drawable folders, as some of the answers have already pointed out..

Answer (score 3):

See [Android Developers: Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: thanks for quick answer @niek ,But Actually i don't want to design different layout for different screen.I just want to use one layout for all size screen support.

Comment: You don't need to use different layouts if you don't want to. You can use different drawable folders with different sized images for the different sizes and densities of screens

Comment: @ ScouseChris : your this comment look like same as my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be independent of screen size, use `dp (dip)` instead of `px` when you design your xml-layouts. And use `sp` when you define text-size.

Comment: Ah ok, can you post some code, without it, it's quite hard to tell what your problem is

Answer (score 0):

You should provide properly sized image resources for the different screen sizes. This can be accomplished in Android using the built in [Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) sdk. It enables you to use the sdp size unit which fits to the screen size.